# Checkbox unchecked on reloading

Tags: python, html, flask

I am working on flask and once I check a checkbox, again when I come back to the same page , checkbox gets unchecked.I want the checkboxes to be checked till the user manually unchecks them .

```
{% for entry in entries %}
<td>    <input type="checkbox" name="pos" value="{{entry.clientid}}" >Verified<    /td>
{% endfor %}
```

this is the html page ,on reloading all the checkboxes gets unchecked again

Comment: Still unclear what you are asking. Do you want to store the state on the server side, or in the web browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the checkbox to be ticked, you need to tell the browser to tick it. You do that using `checked="checked"` inside your `input` field.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pos" value="{{entry.clientid}}" {% if entry.clientid %}checked="checked"{% endif %}>
```

That will tick the checkbox if the `clientid` field on an entry has a value, but you can change it to check whatever value you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try these:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="true">
```